# Minetracks and Redstone - preventing the track from fixing itself

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

This is my current minetrack setup. The red marked part is supposed to go up, such that it works as a booster.

On the left handed side you can see a wire going to the other track that is behind the booster - when it gets triggered (as in the image), the booster track magically resets and disables itself.

Other than wiring a different way, is it possible to prevent that behaviour?

[image]

Comment: Minecart booster tracks no longer work in recent versions of minecraft.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm afraid not. The current triggers the neighboring blocks to update, which resets the slope of the track. Simply move the wiring (and what it connects to) one block further.

Comment: Thanks! But this won't trigger the shunt, right?

Comment: @fjdumont Obviously :) Fixed.

Comment: You could also trigger the track piece with a redstone torch underneath it, and invert the signal from your input using a [NOT gate](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Redstone_circuits#NOT_Gate).

Comment: @Kevin The blocks will still be updated at the next current change.

Comment: Ahh, I misinterpreted the problem.